# Subquery using where

Tags: mysql, sql

Using table below 
![Schema]

It can also be easily replaced with an OUTER JOIN whenever a need arises.

The WHERE syntax is more relational model oriented.

A result of two tables JOIN'ed is a cartesian product of the tables to which a filter is applied which selects only those rows with joining columns matching.

It's easier to see this with the WHERE syntax.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT E_Fname, E_Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E_id in (
  SELECT E_id 
  FROM EMPLOYEE E, STORE S
  WHERE E.E_id = S.Store_Manager_id
    AND UPPER(STORE_SUBURB) = ‘ARMONK’ 
    AND Store_id in (
      SELECT toy_id
      FROM TOY T, STORE S
      WHERE T.toy_id = S.Store_id
  )
)
```

i m not sure if this is correct and how do i add lowest hire income to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it without `where` clauses at all:

```
SELECT SUM(hireTransactionValue) as hireIncome, Store_ID, E_Lname, E_Fname
FROM (
  SELECT Quantity * Hire_price as hireTransactionValue, Store_ID
  FROM HireTransaction
  JOIN Toy ON HireTransaction.Toy_id = Toy.Toy_id 
) TransactionValues
JOIN Store ON Store.Store_id = TransactionValues.Store_ID
JOIN Employee ON store_ManagerID = E_id
GROUP BY Store_ID, E_Lname, E_Fname
ORDER BY hireIncome
```

**Explanation**:
We are going to need a subquery to combine the hire transaction quantities with the rate for the hired toy. So we start with that, all we care about is the transaction value and what store at which it happened. Then we join through `Store` to get the manager `Employee` record. We then `SUM` all those transaction values in groups by store, and sort by the summed transaction values.

(BTW: I'm curious as to what kind of toys - like inflatables or heavy machinery?)

Answer (score -1):

This is my guess, but I will build tables now to confirm it works.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT store_id, E_Fname, E_Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE E, Store
WHERE E.E_id in(

    SELECT E_id 
    FROM EMPLOYEE E, STORE S
    WHERE E.E_id = S.Store_Managerid
    AND UPPER(S.STORE_SUBURB) = 'ARMONK'
    AND S.Store_id in(

        SELECT store_id
            FROM TOY T, STORE S
            WHERE T.toy_id = S.Store_id
            AND min(hire_price)
    )
)
```